# Increase runtime for for loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have the following dataframe

```
   user_id  orderdate       cart
        8 2012-01-01      produce
        8 2012-01-31      produce
        8 2012-03-01      produce
        8 2012-03-11      produce
       10 2012-01-01      produce
       10 2012-01-31      produce
       10 2012-02-12 meat seafood
       10 2012-02-26         deli
       17 2012-01-01    beverages
       17 2012-01-04    beverages
```

and would like to format it to look like

```
  user_id  orderdate         cart         to  ord
        8 2012-01-01      produce 2012-01-30 ord1
        8 2012-01-31      produce 2012-02-29 ord2
        8 2012-03-01      produce 2012-03-10 ord3
        8 2012-03-11      produce 2012-03-31 ord4
        8 2012-04-01      nopurch 2012-04-01 ord5
       10 2012-01-01      produce 2012-01-30 ord1
       10 2012-01-31      produce 2012-02-11 ord2
       10 2012-02-12 meat seafood 2012-02-25 ord3
       10 2012-02-26         deli 2012-03-24 ord4
       10 2012-03-25      nopurch 2012-04-01 ord5
       17 2012-01-01    beverages 2012-01-03 ord1
       17 2012-01-04    beverages 2012-01-08 ord2
       17 2012-01-09    beverages 2012-01-13 ord3
       17 2012-01-14    beverages 2012-01-19 ord4
       17 2012-01-20      nopurch 2012-04-01 ord5
```

I found the following codes to do this but since my dataframe is quite large (140000 rows) the runtime takes more than an hour to run. Is there a way to modify this so it runs faster?

```
max.date <- max(df$orderdate)+1
ids <- unique(df$user_id)
df.new <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(ids)) {

  df.cache <- df %>%
    filter(user_id==ids[i])

  ifelse(nrow(df.cache)==1,
         av.dur <- 30,
         av.dur <- round(((max(df.cache$orderdate) - min(df.cache$orderdate))/(nrow(df.cache)-1))*1.5, 0))

  df.cache <- rbind(df.cache, data.frame(user_id=df.cache$user_id[nrow(df.cache)],
                                         orderdate=max(df.cache$orderdate)+av.dur,
                                         cart='nopurch'))

  ifelse(max(df.cache$orderdate) > max.date,
         df.cache$orderdate[which.max(df.cache$orderdate)] <- max.date,
         NA)

  df.cache$to <- c(df.cache$orderdate[2:nrow(df.cache)]-1, max.date)

  # order# for Sankey diagram
  df.cache <- df.cache %>%
    mutate(ord = paste('ord', c(1:nrow(df.cache)), sep=''))

  df.new <- rbind(df.new, df.cache)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic for how the dates for the final `nopurch` rows get determined. Can you try to explain?

Comment: It was calculated on the max of orderdate column. So the last order for each user_id will have a row consisting of the date of actual order in from column and the max of order date in to column. This will then be used as input to seqformat to convert to STS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve a lot of what you need using some simple `dplyr` operations. I must confess I couldn't really follow what happens with the dates at the last order and beyond, so what's there is basically a placeholder showing how to perform simple operations. But what's there should be much more efficient than your for loop approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = read.table(text = " user_id  orderdate       cart
        8 2012-01-01      produce
                8 2012-01-31      produce
                8 2012-03-01      produce
                8 2012-03-11      produce
                10 2012-01-01      produce
                10 2012-01-31      produce
                10 2012-02-12 meat_seafood
                10 2012-02-26         deli
                17 2012-01-01    beverages
                17 2012-01-04    beverages", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$orderdate = as.Date(df$orderdate)

df = df %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    do(add_row(., cart = "nopurch", orderdate = max(.$orderdate) + days(1), user_id = .$user_id[1])) %>%
    arrange(user_id, orderdate) %>%
    mutate(to = lead(orderdate) - days(1),
           ord = paste0("ord", seq_along(orderdate)))
```

Output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   user_id [3]
   user_id  orderdate         cart         to   ord
     <int>     <date>        <chr>     <date> <chr>
 1       8 2012-01-01      produce 2012-01-30  ord1
 2       8 2012-01-31      produce 2012-02-29  ord2
 3       8 2012-03-01      produce 2012-03-10  ord3
 4       8 2012-03-11      produce 2012-03-11  ord4
 5       8 2012-03-12      nopurch         NA  ord5
 6      10 2012-01-01      produce 2012-01-30  ord1
 7      10 2012-01-31      produce 2012-02-11  ord2
 8      10 2012-02-12 meat_seafood 2012-02-25  ord3
 9      10 2012-02-26         deli 2012-02-26  ord4
10      10 2012-02-27      nopurch         NA  ord5
11      17 2012-01-01    beverages 2012-01-03  ord1
12      17 2012-01-04    beverages 2012-01-04  ord2
13      17 2012-01-05      nopurch         NA  ord3
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. It seems to work. And it takes 1/10th the time than previous.